# Display default text in a SpinnerAdapter (For an ActionBar navigation)

Tags: android

I've had a look at the documentation, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to approach this.

This is what I'm doing:

```
mActionBar = getActionBar();
mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.platform_list,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

What I'm trying to do is give the dropdown list a default value - "Please Select a Type", when the application loads up and nothing is selected yet. This is because the selection will trigger a change in the listview fragment displayed below, and without a selection (at startup) i would like to display a simple placeholder image or something.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I also need to implement a dropdown on action bar. While using a spinner, I have the same problem as you. While using a submenu (as a workaround), I got the element (like your "Please select...") in action bar, but it's without a little triangle in bottom right corner indicating that there is the drop down. When I use the spinner, the triangle is shown automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the selection of the Spinner to a particular position which can display this text

```
public void setSelection (int position)

Since: API Level 1
Sets the currently selected item. To support accessibility subclasses that 
override this   method must invoke the overriden super method first.
Parameters

position    Index (starting at 0) of the data item to be selected.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: Yeah, but would there be any way to remove the item after the spinner is opened? Because it's not actually a valid input...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that what you want is a SpinnerAdapter? I spent a while today trying to figure out the same problem until I realised that what I actually wanted was just a [SubMenu](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear you problem to me.But i guess you want to view a default view and after select anything you want to change the below list view.If i am correct you can do this like this.

create onItemSelectedListener

```
class Ranger implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

        item= parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        //if the selected item is default do default things
        //or else do the list view update
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Basically i want to have a default text ("Pick an option") then when the user opens the spinner, then that option is not there, merely the proper options ("option 1", "option 2" etc) I know how to change views and all that, but im just stuck on how to have a default value (if it's possible at all) cheers!